# How can I properly make AJAX POST request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I need some help. I can't make POST request with javascript.. I don't want to use jQuery in a first place. I don't know why my $_POST is empty..

This is my scores.php file.

```
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$file   = __DIR__ . '/scores.json';
$scores = file_get_contents($file);

if ($method === 'GET') {
echo $scores;
} else if ($method === 'POST') {
$scores   = json_decode($scores, TRUE);
$scores[] = [
    'name'   => $_POST['name'],
    'scores' => (int) $_POST['scores'],
];

usort($scores, function($a, $b) {
    $scoresA = $a['scores'];
    $scoresB = $b['scores'];

    if ($scoresA === $scoresB) {
        return 0;
    }

    return $scoresA < $scoresB ? 1 : -1;
});

$scores = json_encode($scores);

file_put_contents($file, $scores);

echo $scores;
} else {
echo 'Method not allowed.';
}
```

And this is some of my code in frogGame.js file:

```
function setScores(){
let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "scores.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("name=Henry&scores=2542");

}

setScores();
```

Comment: You are posting query string but expecting JSON. Change POST to GET and see if you are getting anything, then simplify the POST until you get something and then start adding the more complex code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this:

```
function setScores(){
  let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("POST", "scores.php?name=Henry&scores=2542", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send();
}
setScores();
```